# Split on space but not if there is a colon followed by space or if there is a space in quotes

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

```
str = 'name: phil age : 23 range: 33, 45 address: "main ave US"'
```

to be tokenized as

```
['name: phil', 'age : 23', 'range: 33, 45' 'address: "main ave US"']
```

Comment: This isn't really a pure regex operation.  What language are you using?  Also, what is the source of this data?  It almost looks like JSON, and if it were you would just use a JSON parser.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't even match your description. This is **not** what regex is meant to do. You should use a dedicated lexer/parser.

Comment: It is not JSON. The source is a raw string entered as it is in the input box.

Comment: @dilip which programming language are you using?

Comment: The problem as it seems that the string is not following any useful patterns as such e.g. discrepancy between `name:` and `age :`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample string 1

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'name: phil age : 23 range: 33, 45 address: "main ave US"' 
>>> re.findall(r'\w+\s*:\s*(?:"[^"]*"|.*?(?=\w+\s*:\s*|$))', str)
['name: phil ', 'age : 23 ', 'range: 33, 45 ', 'address: "main ave US"']
```

Sample string 2

```
>>> str = 'name: phil age : 23 range: 33, 45 address: "main ave US" abcd : xyz' 
>>> re.findall(r'\w+\s*:\s*(?:"[^"]*"|.*?(?=\w+\s*:\s*|$))', str)
['name: phil ', 'age : 23 ', 'range: 33, 45 ', 'address: "main ave US"', 'abcd : xyz']
```

Sample string 3

```
>>> str = 'name: phil age : 23 range: 33, 45'
>>> re.findall(r'\w+\s*:\s*(?:"[^"]*"|.*?(?=\w+\s*:\s*|$))', str)
['name: phil ', 'age : 23 ', 'range: 33, 45']
```

To trim the leading and trailing spaces of each match you can use this:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x:x.strip(), re.findall(r'\w+\s*:\s*(?:"[^"]*"|.*?(?=\w+\s*:\s*|$))', str)))
['name: phil', 'age : 23', 'range: 33, 45']
```

Regex used is: `\w+\s*:\s*(?:"[^"]*"|.*?(?=\w+\s*:\s*|$))`

---

Edge case:

```
>>> str='word1 word2 name: phil age : 23 range: 33, 45'
>>> list(map(lambda x:x.strip() if ':' in x else list(map(lambda s:s.strip(), x.split())), re.findall(r'\w+\s*:?\s*(?:"[^"]*"|.*?(?=\w+\s*:\s*|$))?' , str)))
[['word1', 'word2'], 'name: phil', 'age : 23', 'range: 33, 45']
```

Once you have the above structure you can flatten the list using any 1 of the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: I would have accepted this answer, but as you mentioned, it does not work for all the cases, e.g str = 'name: phil age : 23 range: 33, 45'
Thanks for your efforts though

Comment: @dilip edited the ans with examples and a new regex .. have a look now

Comment: Perfect. This works. Thanks. If possible can you also look into one corner case str = 'word1 word2 name: phil age : 23 range: 33, 45' => ['word1', 'word2', 'name: phil ', 'age : 23 ', 'range: 33, 45']. But you answered as per the question and I am accepting it. Brilliant job. Just would be glad if you can handle the above edge case as well.

Comment: +1 but you can improve the pattern with a few small modifications. 1) You can shorten the lookahead to just `(?=\w+\s*:|$)` (removed the `\s*` after the colon). 2) You don't need the `"[^"]*"|` part at all. 3) Add `\s*` to the lookahead to get rid of the trailing whitespace. Basically it should look like this: `\w+\s*:\s*.*?(?=\s*\w+\s*:|$)`. _Update to work with OP's new requirement:_ `\w+(?:\s*:\s*.*?(?=\s*\w+\s*:|$))?`.

Comment: @dilip weclome :) sure .. I'm amidst something .. will try to include that and post in sometime

Comment: @Rawing if the value is double quoted and has a colon, it would break, hence in that case `"[^"]*"` would be necessary; regarding `\s*` removal in the positive look-ahead and adding \s* at the start for trailing spaces is a good point

Answer (score 1):

This regex should be pretty stable. It only checks for the key name followed by a colon and treats that both as start of a match and as not included end, using a positive lookahead.

Depending on how you want to further process it, you can either use the simple variant:

```
\w+\s*:.*?(?=(?:\w+\s*:)|$)
```

This will match the entire key/value pair including all spaces.

[Check this regex out on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cW7cI3/2)

---

If you're going to split the pairs up at the colon anyway, e.g. to store them in a dictionary, you could as well use this slightly modified regex that returns a tuple `(key, value)` for each pair, with leading and trailing spaces already stripped:

```
(\w+)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=(?:\w+\s*:)|$)
```

[Check this regex out on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mG5jF4/2)

---

Here's a Python example how to use both regexes:

```
import re

pattern1 = r'\w+\s*:.*?(?=(?:\w+\s*:)|$)'
pattern2 = r'(\w+)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=(?:\w+\s*:)|$)'
data = 'name: phil age : 23 range: 33, 45 address: "main ave US"' 

print('Pattern 1:', re.findall(pattern1, data))
print('Pattern 2:', re.findall(pattern2, data))
```

Output:

```
Pattern 1: ['name: phil ', 'age : 23 ', 'range: 33, 45 ', 'address: "main ave US"']
Pattern 2: [('name', 'phil'), ('age', '23'), ('range', '33, 45'), ('address', '"main ave US"')]
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Yi1vil)